# Stack Overflow Teams, team upvoting

Tags: discussion, voting, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm a bit confused on Stack Overflow's policy for upvoting team members.
To the best of my understanding the policy before was that voting for question of your teammate can appear like Voter-fraud, and it's best not to do so.

But now with the release of Stack Overflow teams, this changes your environment to view posts made specifically by team members, in a way doesn't this product promote to vote for team members?

Comment: Aside: I am in favour of gamification in general, while being aware of the psychological ramifications that result in a potentially negative user experience. I do wonder whether being downvoted anonymously by a person who you know is a team member might not make for a harmonious working environment, though!

Comment: The distinction is minor.  At the public site it is evil, in the Team product it is pointless.  Golden rule applies either way, vote for content and not people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stack Overflow doesn't moderate content in your Team. They explicitly don't have access to the Teams content except in extreme cases. They're not looking for voting rings - you literally *are* a voting ring, as most Teams are probably fewer than 50-100 people, though I don't know the official numbers here.

I think it's very unlikely that one of your Team admins will accuse you of always upvoting Alice's posts and downvoting Shannon's... the thing you should always keep in mind is that **you should only be voting on posts you think are high quality and accurate**, whether on your Team or the wider site. Who writes the post should be irrelevant either way.

When bringing that to the full site, nothing has changed. You're definitely better safe than sorry to avoid voting for your coworkers/Team members. You absolutely shouldn't be *targeting* your voting at them and if you're working on something that's really obscure or limited to your Team's specific interests, you should avoid voting for it in case there are many such overlapping points of expertise. That said, on bigger subjects with many experts, if you organically come across a post that someone you know wrote (e.g. through search) I think that the frequency of your voting for Team members would be very low. Heck, you may not even know the Stack Overflow usernames of all these people!

As far as I'm aware, nothing about sharing a Team with someone makes their full-site content more prevalent in search results, so this shouldn't be an issue at all.