# To what extent is Stack Overflow for Teams subject to the Code of Conduct and general site policies?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, behavior, code-of-conduct

At first, I thought it was obvious that Stack Overflow for Teams would be subject to the full [Code of Conduct (CoC)](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and other applicable content and behavior policies, however Catija ♦ [mentioned in an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367497/6471538),

> Stack Overflow doesn't moderate content in your Team. They explicitly don't have access to the Teams content except in extreme cases. They're not looking for voting rings....

While this was said in the context of voting rings/serial voting (seemingly implying that it's acceptable, but discouraged, to engage in serial voting within a Team as long as it doesn't spread onto the public Stack), it made me wonder what other kinds of behavior are allowed in Teams that would be disallowed on the regular, public SO stack. I suppose "extreme cases" include unlawful content and criminal behavior (e.g. using Teams to plan a heist, posting unlawful images, using Teams to leak classified documents, etc.), but does the line stop at unlawful behavior, or do "extreme cases" also include legal behavior that violates Stack Overflow values? What behaviors *that are forbidden on the main stack* are *allowed* on a Team as long as they stay within the Team? For example, is it acceptable to:

- Spam a Team
- Post Rude messages, i.e. messages that "[a] reasonable person would find...inappropriate for respectful discourse", but that are considered appropriate within the social context of the Team
- Engage in bigotry, if bigotry is one of the values of the Team
- Not be open for feedback
- Fail to include an MCVE when posting a debugging request
- Post questions that would be too broad, unclear, or opinion-based for the main site (e.g. "What database do you think we should use for the QXR Phase 1 Project?" or "How can we solve this really complex thing that only people who work here would know about and that isn't explained in the text of this question?")
- Post non-programming questions (e.g. "Where do I get a parking pass for our downtown building?", "What is the correct timesheet code for working on the payroll system?", or "Should Bill be kicked off the team?")
- Post NAA answers, including posting Link-Only Answers or using answers to "bump" a question

I'm not asking whether a Team has the authority to make their own decisions on how and when to take action against these kinds of behaviors within the context of their own team. I'm asking whether Stack Overflow and/or Stack Exchange intends to do so. E.g. if a Team member contacts Stack Overflow and says, "User bjones on Team Whatever keeps posting 'Answers' to his own questions saying 'I need a status update on this item by Friday, failure to do so will result in employee discipline'", will Stack Overflow just say, "Deal with it in your Team or else leave it" or will they come in, delete the NAA content, and possibly suspend bjones for low-quality content or rule violations?

Comment: Is SO-Teams per definition restriced to programming questions? I always thought that a team can contain questions for whatever topic the team wants.

Comment: @BDL I thought it wasn't, that it is branded "SO for Teams" rather than "SE for Teams", "Server Fault for Teams", "Yog-Sothoth Abominations for Eldritch Teams Outside Time and Space" or whatever for *marketing* purposes rather than *content moderation* purposes, but I thought it would be helpful to have a clear official word.

Comment: SO for Teams has nothing to do with SO, except that it's hosted under the same domain and has linked user accounts. If you have problems with users in your team, you have to handle that within your organization.

Comment: Sounds like a pure [workplace.se] question

Comment: I think a more useful frame of mind is to see teams like a stripped down version of enterprise. The teams admins and the org paying controls everything on that team, and SE explicitly disclaims the right to even see the content (which makes sense considering there could be high value business secrets there).

Answer (score 20):

It doesn't apply to all.

**We do not have access to a Team's content** unless they have a support issue they need help with and an admin for their Team provides written consent to access their Team to look into the issue. We'd otherwise have absolutely no clue what is being posted there.

Each Team is responsible for moderating itself in whatever manner it chooses. The admins of that Team are essentially the diamond moderators.

A couple other things to keep in mind:

- There are no flags in Teams, as there is no flags queue for admins to view.
- There are no suspensions in Teams. If a user is causing problems, they can just deactivate their access to the Team.

Comment: Does this translate 100% to free teams as well? meaning admins there can be as abusive as they want with no repercussions? (particularly for teams that aren't business related)

Comment: @KevinB Yes. We have the same access to Free teams as any other Team - none.

Answer (score 13):

Given that the idea of Teams is to provide a place where people who work together on something can create a repository of knowledge about that thing, then issues such as spam, rudeness, hate speech etc. become a workplace disciplinary issue rather than a site moderation issue.

The members of the team should know each other, if not personally then as someone else in their organisation.

The sanctions for breaking the rules are much more serious than losing access to the site for a number of days, it could actually lead to dismissal from your job.