# Is spam, by the definition in the help center, prohibited on private teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, spam

Assuming the admins allow it, is a post that is considered spam by the [definition in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) allowed on private teams, and if not, what actions should a non-admin take if the admins are posting spam?

How is this a duplicate of [To what extent is Stack Overflow for Teams subject to the Code of Conduct and general site policies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374434/8384089)?  The answers there are completely different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To what extent is Stack Overflow for Teams subject to the Code of Conduct and general site policies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374434/to-what-extent-is-stack-overflow-for-teams-subject-to-the-code-of-conduct-and-ge): *"spam, rudeness, hate speech etc. become a workplace disciplinary issue rather than a site moderation issue."*, *"Each Team is responsible for moderating itself in whatever manner it chooses."*

Comment: The dupe doesn't appear to address at all the second half of this question: "*...what actions should a non-admin take if the admins are posting spam?*" Are there any tools akin to "moderation" on a Team? What do those look like?

Comment: @zcoop98 Good point, I'm voting to reopen the question.

Comment: @zcoop98 *"There are no suspensions in Teams. If a user is causing problems, they can just deactivate their access to the Team."* - Get in touch with an admin if you're not an admin, seem pretty obvious to me

Comment: @Nick I meant, how do you report to someone other then the admins?  That isn't answered by the other question.

Comment: @Anonymous Your MD?, your admins manager?, there'll always be someone higher up

Comment: You don't. Maybe go to HR if the team is run by an actual company

Comment: Given that an admin (presumably the person creating spam in your theoretical(?) case) has to provide written permission for SO staff to look at the team, the only action you could presumably take short of leaving is speaking to them.

Comment: @Nick I mean, someone from SO who isn't in your team.  If the only admin violates the CoC, that may be necessary.

Comment: @Anonymous ? people on SO not in your team are irrelevant, they don't have access to your team, what do you mean?

Comment: FYI, the team being discussed here is likely not business releated, for those of you wholly confused how this could even be a problem.

Comment: In teams that aren't for a company, it's really up to the admins. There's always the option to leave the team in extreme cases, though

Comment: IMO, given that teams has a free tier now and thus non-business teams are more likely, it might be worth having the current policy revisited. Hosting a private area for people with 0 oversight can create some pretty toxic places, surely there needs to exist some form of process for a non-admin user of a given non-business team to escalate potential abuse cases. (if anything, just update the dupe target)

Comment: @KevinB And for personal attacks...

Comment: If the person running the team is the problem it might be time to reorganize the team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spamming, and many other bad behaviors like harassment, are still **no bueno** within a Team. But in that case it's governed by the [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/free), which say the following for all levels:

> Stack Overflow will generally not interrupt or interfere with the use of the Product. However, Stack Overflow does not condone the use of Product for the following activities, and reserves the right to terminate or otherwise refuse access/use of Product to Company and/or any Entity Representative and/or Authorized User for the following reasons:
>
> - Engaging in spamming or automated and uninvited communications within and/or outside of the Product

Though it's not easy to see how a Team could be used for the type of spam that public SO sees (and quickly deletes), much less how someone would be caught as developers [only get access to a Team to help with support issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374434/to-what-extent-is-stack-overflow-for-teams-subject-to-the-code-of-conduct-and-ge).