# Can I use Stack Overflow for Teams for non-programming questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm looking into using Stack Overflow for Teams (SOfT) as a general knowledge management system for our company. We are a management consulting company, so we do not write code for a living. Our questions are more likely to be about solving organisational problems, writing proposals for clients, doing profitability / productivity analysis, solving industry specific problems, etc. Is it appropriate to use SOfT for this purpose?

I can see that Stack Exchange is used for many purposes other than programming, but I am not sure if SOfT could or should be used in the same way.

Comment: Yeap, that's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: From what we know (or, I have heard personally), yes, [SOfT can be used for *anything*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374434/2821954).

Comment: I don't think it's a good dupe target. It has no answer. Maybe the dupe should be the other way around.

Comment: I agree - not only the target does not have an answer (unlike this one!), it is closed as a dupe of the announcement, and I cannot, for the love of all things holy, find *anything* in the huge list of answers that definitevely says "yes, it can"/"no, it cannot". If anything, the announcement implies engineering teams as the target audience, wheareas in reality Teams are not limited to them. I voted to reopen.

Comment: You pay for it, you can use it however you like.

Comment: @AndrewT. - Anything ... except things that are forbidden by the Terms of Use.

Comment: Of course. Teams is not subject to off-topic restrictions that the main site has. You could ask about unicorns, and it would be fine.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes. I'm member of two Teams, one for ♦ moderators and another one for the spam-fighting organization [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/). Programming questions are non-existent on the former and a rare bird on the latter; it's mostly support questions about how to use various tools and discussions about policies.

Basically, anything that fits in an (objective) Q&A format will work on Stack Overflow for Teams, just like it does for the Stack Exchange network in general. It's called Stack *Overflow* for Teams because the name Stack Overflow is much more well-known than Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 18):

To add on to what Glorfindel said, Teams is entirely separate from the Stack Overflow Q&A site as far as content moderation goes. As a diamond moderator, I cannot see your team, let alone moderate it. Your rules inside the Team would be determined by the Admin users, as they are also your content moderators.

Answer (score 13):

It's your instance - feel free to use it for whatever topic(s) you deem appropriate. No one is going to tell you not to do that.

Comment: OP asks whether it's an appropriate tool for their purposes, not whether he'd be *allowed* to use it that way.

Comment: @CrisLuengo They ask if it "could *or* should" be used for that purposes. The answer is "yes, use it for any topic you want."