# Reputation from Stack Overflow Enterprise

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-enterprise

I recently changed jobs and left behind 15k reputation and 115 badges on a private Stack Overflow Enterprise instance. It took me several years to earn that. Is there any way that could be anonymized and added to my public account? I'm guessing over 22 million people in every country on earth would want the same thing.

To be clear, I am not suggesting the reputation from a private SOE instance should be added to my SO rep. Just like when someone participates in multiple communities, you can see their rep in each community. See the answer and comments from EJoshuaS for example.

Comment: Interesting that people thinks its a bad question. You have no ability to see why I would ask?

Comment: From a technical standpoint, this is not possible. Not only do we not have access to the data within private Teams/Enterprise instances by design, but trying to link everything together like this would be a security nightmare. Not even a slightest chance this would happen.

Comment: Side note: it is good idea to re-read [what is reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) - if such proposal would be implemented you, @5eleven7, would be considered very trusted on some site and hence generally aware of the SE rules. Unfortunately your comment immediately shows that it is not the case: commenting about votes is off-topic and not knowing what "Feature-request" is for ("people thinks its a bad question") as well as borderline being rude ("You have no ability to see why I would ask?") is not something that is expected of 10K+ user of SE...

Comment: I would agree with your comment in any other Stack Exchange network. Here is where we debate the Stack Exchange norms.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta don't necessarily indicate people think the question is bad, just that they disagree. See [What do votes mean on Meta? Why was my well-written post downvoted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/259918#259918)

Comment: As pointed out, votes on feature requests typically indicate disagreement, not perceived question quality. Currently, 2 voters want this feature to be enacted and 28 voters don't. Personally, I don't see any issue with the question quality, I just don't agree that this feature should be created.

Comment: Also, something to keep in mind: the assumption embedded in your comment is that if people understood what you're saying they would agree with you (so the fact that they don't agree must indicate that they don't understand). That assumption is patently untrue; sometimes people just disagree with you.

Comment: The link provided by @TylerH helped me understand the response here. This is all good debate about the idea and I appreciate the reasons given about transparency. Personally I worked hard for that rep and want to keep it, but I see why its not going to happen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, that's not how reputation works; your reputation is locked to your account, which is locked to the site your account is on.

Reputation is also tied to posts. The posts that earned you all that reputation would need to be migrated to Stack Overflow, and that would violate the Terms of Service of the product being a *private* SO Enterprise instance.

That's not to mention that allowing a privately-moderated instance of Stack Overflow to have its user reputation merged with the public Stack Overflow would open up a huge vector for abuse.

If the content that earned you reputation is not proprietary or copyrighted, and you remember some of it, you can always post well-formed self-answered Q&A posts that cover the same content (assuming it's on-topic in the public SO instance). If the content is useful and high quality, you'll start earning reputation here in no time.

Comment: I think you're right about the abuse potential - there could easily be voting rings that are invisible to the "main" Q&A site because not even SE staff can moderate private instances.

Comment: All the activity on all the sites I participate in is valid. I would like to see it all in one place.

Comment: @5eleven7 You can see your _public_ network reputation at https://stackexchange.com/users/8274862/5eleven7?tab=accounts, but separate instances of SO enterprise are separate. Consider them not part of the "Stack Exchange Network", because they're isolated silos by design.

Comment: @TylerH I completely understand that is the current truth. My question is a feature request asking to change that, and I'm shocked folks don't understand the desire.

Comment: @5eleven7 I understand the desire, I just don't think it is realistic, and for good reason.

Comment: @5eleven7 Even if all of *your* activity is legitimate, someone else that was less well-intentioned who wanted to use that feature to game the system could easily do so. It would be very easy to set up a voting ring in a private instance to make it look like I'm creating great content somewhere that no one else can see. Heck, I could be the next Jon Skeet in a few days without even having to generate any real content.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica This is possible, but doesn't impact my interest in the feature request.

Comment: @5eleven7: But it *does* impact whether other people think it's a good feature request. I'm shocked that you don't understand the concern, and I'm guessing that over 22 million people in every country on earth would have the same concern.

Comment: @5eleven7 Oh, it's more than possible. People get caught trying to game the reputation system all the time; if we gave people a way to do that without any risk of being caught, I'm quite sure that people would do it.

Answer (score 11):

This would make little sense because the voting, moderation, and topic standards are completely different. In fact, private instances [don't even have to be about programming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415728/can-i-use-stack-overflow-for-teams-for-non-programming-questions). That being said, many questions that were upvoted there likely would've been downvoted and closed here (and *vice versa*).

By analogy, I have 12k reputation on Literature Stack Exchange, but it has no bearing on my Stack Overflow account because they're completely different sites.

Comment: Right, but you are able to view all of the reputation from the different Stack Exchange networks you participate in. Literature 12.3k, Stack Overflow 10.9k, Science Fiction & Fantasy 5.7k, The Workplace 5k, Meta Stack Exchange 4.9k

Comment: "reputation on Literature Stack Exchange, but it has no bearing on my Stack Overflow account" - this actually not exactly true - SE grants default reputation on new site as long as you have enough reputation on any SE site. This works because SE public sites have relatively similar rules unlike private once. I.e. this question and comment  by @5eleven7 show complete misunderstanding how "feature-request" and Meta in general work presumably because there is no such concepts on their private instance where their earn 10K+ points - totally unexpected from one with 10K rep from any of SE sites.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You have zero insight into how our internal SOE instance was managed. In fact, it was deliberately quite similar to the public version. I was an elected moderator, and we continuously emphasized to the user base that we followed the same rules as public, just with proprietary questions.

Comment: @5eleven7: " You have zero insight into how our internal SOE instance was managed" - exactly, and that's why it would be meaningless. Anyone could create a private SOE instance purely for the sake of sock-puppeting their way to millions of reputation. There would be no accountability because there'd be no visibility into how the reputation was earned, making it essentially pointless.

Comment: @5eleven7 Not only can you see the reputation, you can see the content that helped me get the reputation in the first place. You're perfectly free to vote either way on my Q&A depending on whether you agree that it's helpful content or not, and you can flag for moderator intervention if you think I got any of my rep through sock puppetry or voting rings.

Comment: @JonSkeet My point exactly - even if they *weren't* using sock puppets or voting rings to get the rep (which we'd have no way of knowing), it would be impossible to have any context for what the rep even meant because we don't know what topics are allowed there or what the quality standards are. All we'd know is that they're an expert in... well... whatever it is they ask about on that instance. At least on public sites I can read their help center to know what the site is about and what their quality standards are.