# Why is the removal of Teams from stackoverflow.com necessitating the removal of all ties?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I belong to a fair number of SO Teams and SO is in the process of moving everything to https://stackoverflowteams.com This is a good change (it really should have been rolled up this way, since having it under the same domain [was clearly confusing for users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415728/2370483)).

SE is, however, throwing the baby out with the bath water.

Some of the "freemium" teams have been moved to this new domain, which removes them from the side bar. Other Teams (including paid) will be moved later. What this does is decrease the chances I ever see a Teams post. In fact, I suspect this will *drastically reduce user involvement from overlapping SE users*. I only see some of these teams *because* of the side bar and global inbox. The problems I'm having here are

1. There's no links to the new place for Teams. The side bar has added this oddball tooltip that... really doesn't tell you anything

   [image: SO Teams?]

   I get that there will be a redirect if I know the URL but... why isn't there a link here? It's like two of my teams just vanished into thin air. Check my email? Why do I have to do an extra step here? How about a link to the new domain by itself at least?
2. The global inbox on Teams is gone. There's one on the new domain, but it's now a... whole page called "For You"? What happened to the familiar SE dropdown inbox? Can we at least have an option to see either a "Teams inbox" on SO/SE proper, or the Teams notices in the current global inbox? And the "For You" page doesn't clear notices like the SE global inbox.

I get that SO is trying to make this product more "mature", since it is a revenue source for SO. It's needed its own ecosystem for a long time. I just think that some of the existing use cases (that SO directly uses themselves) are going to be hampered by this. It would be helpful to reconsider trying to remove *everything* linking to Teams.

Comment: Where is this "For You" page?

Comment: @Dharman It's on the "Stack Overflow Teams" site. The URL structure is `https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/TEAMNAMEHERE/for-you`

Comment: @Machavity A bit off-topic but I'm curious... do mods not have the ability to add a [status-*] tag in the first revision? Or did you just happen to consider adding it after posting the question?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine: They do have the ability to add it right away. But I know I've made some typos or wanted to edit the title after initially posting a question in the past, so I can understand waiting to do so after the fact. (Adding the [status-review] tag creates an internal ticket for us, and any subsequent edits to the title would result in duplicate tickets.)

Comment: Related: [What does Teams getting its own domain mean practically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420980/1478931)

Comment: FYI, it looks like the "[*stackoverflowteams.com*](https://stackoverflowteams.com/)" text in that message is now actually formatted as a link to the domain, too, instead of just being (italicized) plaintext.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get to the meat of your question "**Why is the removal of Teams from stackoverflow.com necessitating the removal of all ties?**", we’re currently decoupling Stack Overflow for Teams from stackoverflow.com as part of a larger project to achieve SOC 2 Type 2 and ISO 27001 certification in the future. I can’t go into further detail at this time (a more detailed Meta post is coming later next year). This also helps Stack Overflow better service, test, and improve Teams without making infrastructure changes to our public site (and vice-versa),

**Why are some of my Teams still on stackoverflow.com and some are on stackoverflowteams.com?**

We are phasing migrations over the month of November, with the goal of migrating all Teams by December 6, 2022. After all of the Teams are migrated, you will be able to select from any of your associated Teams from the top nav dropdown menu.

**How do I find my Team after migration to stackoverflowteams.com?**

There are a number of ways to find your migrated team:

- All users received an email with their new URL.
- Visit https://stackoverflowteams.com (no team specified) and log in. Login processes will vary depending on whether your Team uses SSO, a third-party IdP, or other credentials. Once you have logged in, you will be able to visit any of your teams associated with your account.
- The new URL follows the format `https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/YourTeamName/` where `YourTeamName` is replaced with your Team’s stub name. If you are a member of multiple Teams associated with the same email address or account, you will be able to switch between your teams using the Top bar selector:

[image]

We recommend updating your bookmarks to your new Teams site.

**Where do I get more information about the domain migration?**

You can read more about the domain migration in the ["Teams Domain Migration" Help Doc](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/6649858-teams-domain-migration), which was shared with users when we announced the migration and again as they are scheduled for migration.

**What is “For You”? How is it different than the Inbox?**

[For You](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4836716-content-picked-for-you) is a personalized feed where users are notified when content they created or share an interest in has been updated. Users can get up to speed quickly by filtering for only unread notifications or by type and save time by marking all as "read" with one click. They can also snooze notifications by setting reminders to complete tasks at a later date/time.

Inbox notifications were automatically migrated to the For You page earlier this year.

Comment: *SOC* = *[System and Organization Controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_and_Organization_Controls#Types)*. [SOC 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_and_Organization_Controls#Types): Report type *"Trust Services Criteria"*

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but why are there no links to the new Teams address anywhere? Even a link to the new site would be helpful

Comment: To me, this does not seem to engage with the question that was asked very clearly.  It seems like it is answering some other question than the ones that were asked.  The question didn't ask, "Why is Teams on a new domain?"  The question did ask, "Why isn't there a link to the new Teams site?", and that isn't answered here.  The question didn't ask "What is For You?"  It asked, "Can we see Teams notices in the global SE inbox?", and that isn't answered here.