# How do I see the Stack Overflow teams I am member of?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I can log in as my user on https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk and I do not see my team:

[image]

However, when I go to https://stackoverflowteams.com/ and log in, I am redirected to my Teams page https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/avt-gts/questions, so I guess I am a member of that team.

Is there a possibility so that I could see what teams I am member of, instead of having to type a completely separate site URL? Is there a link or something between them?

This has changed some time ago. I remember when asking a question on Stack Overflow, I needed to check that the question was public or not. Now I can just ask the question without setting anything. And also I can't navigate to the Stack Overflow Teams site without explicitly inputting https://stackoverflowteams.com/ in the browser URL bar; I have not found a link on https://stackoverflow.com site that would redirect me to my teams. Is there one?

Comment: Teams and [so] are being separated; so that link you provided an image of is likely to disappear in the future. The teams weren't all moved at the same time, so I doubt that'll happen until *all* the teams have been moved. [Stack Overflow Teams](https://stackoverflowteams.com/) is the URL you want for your Stack Overflow Teams.

Comment: Related: [What does Teams getting its own domain mean practically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420980/2821954), [Why is the removal of Teams from stackoverflow.com necessitating the removal of all ties?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421496/2821954)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to focus on one issue. While I understand the connections between the issues you've mentioned, your question is currently a mix of a support request ("where can I find the list of my Teams") and a feature request ("please have a *bit* more connectivity between SO and Teams, so getting there is easier"). It would be much better if those were two separate questions. Both of those issues are important and useful to have answers, but the treatment of them is different: the support question can just be answered, while the feature request would have to be escalated to SE.

Comment: Re-reading this, it's unclear to me if you're A) really asking just a support question of wanting to see a list of your teams, somewhere on either SO/SE public sites or [stackoverflowteams.com (SOT)](//stackoverflowteams.com/); B) wanting just a link to SOT, that isn't the "create a new Team" link, somewhere in the UI on SO/SE public sites; C) wanting links to each of your teams somewhere in the SO/SE public sites UI; or D) all of the above. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you're asking, and, preferably, separate out the [tag:support] question from the [tag:feature-request] issues.